# throttling jenkins parallel in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I came across this message with the code below
in [JENKINS-44085](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44085).

If I already have a map of branches that contains 50 items, but I want to parallel them 5 at a time, how do I need to modify this code? 
My code already has a map of 50 items in a var named branches.

```
// put a number of items into the queue to allow that number of branches to run
for (int i=0;i<MAX_CONCURRENT;i++) {
    latch.offer("$i")
}

for (int i=0; i < 500; i++) {
    def name = "$i"
    branches[name] = {
        def thing = null
        // this will not allow proceeding until there is something in the queue.
        waitUntil {
            thing = latch.pollFirst();
            return thing != null;
        }
        try {
            echo "Hello from $name"
            sleep time: 5, unit: 'SECONDS'
            echo "Goodbye from $name"
        }
        finally {
           // put something back into the queue to allow others to proceed
            latch.offer(thing)
        }
    }
}

timestamps {
    parallel branches
}
```

Comment: The usual Jenkins way of doing so (at least in my opinion) would be to limit the number of executors per build agent. This would then add 50 sub-jobs to the Build Queue, which are then processed as soon as a build agent is available. Maybe that also works for you.

Comment: I thought the number parallel tasks = numbers of executors.  I have a single build agent, whereby I want to throttle how many run concurrent.  But it doesn't seem to do that.  In a declarative pipeline, it seems like it tries to run parallel the # of tasks that are in the map, regardless of the number of executors i have defined.

Comment: Could I somehow use a queue or stack perhaps to pass to parallel?

Comment: Ah, I think now I see your "problem". You're not allocating an executor using the `node` step. Not sure, I'd say you should do that. But maybe not for incredible 500 tasks? Do you want to run this on multiple build agents or not?

Comment: The semaphore from https://github.com/jenkinsci/concurrent-step-plugin should work.

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit old, but for me the problem was also relevant yesterday. In some cases your Jenkins jobs may be light on Jenkins but high on some other system, so you want to limit it for that system. In my opinion using max executors per build agent is not the right way to do that because if your Jenkins cluster scales you will have to adjust stuff.

To answer your question, you probably want to do something like this:

- Create a branches map with numeric indexes "0", "1", etc.
- In the try block of that code you pasted have something like: `build(my_branches[name])`

At least that's how I was using that same workaround before. But then someone at work pointed out a better solution. I also commented this simpler solution in the Jira ticket you refered to. It requires the Lockable Resources Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin

- Go to: `http://<your Jenkins URL>/configure` and add X lockable resources with label "XYZ".
- Use in your code as such:

```
def tests = [:]
for (...) {
    def test_num="$i"
    tests["$test_num"] = {
        lock(label: "XYZ", quantity: 1, variable: "LOCKED") {
            println "Locked resource: ${env.LOCKED}"
            build(job: jobName, wait: true, parameters: parameters)
        }
    }
}
parallel tests
```

The nice thing about this is that you can use this across different jobs. In our case different jobs have a load on XYZ so having these global locks are very handy.

Comment: Yet another example: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44085?focusedCommentId=354852&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-354852