# How to run for loop in batch of 4 for 20 items at once in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have to run for loop in groovy for 40 items, but do wish to run it for 4 items in parallel then next batch and so on. I know of parallel deployments in jenkinsfile but it triggers all 40 at once.

```
          def i = 0
          mslist.collate(4).each{
               build job: 'deploy', parameters: [string(name: 'PROJECT', value: "${it[i]}"), string(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', value: params.ENVIRONMENT)]
               i=i+1
}
```

My Updated code:

```
stages {
    stage ('Parallel Deployments') {
      steps {
        script {
          def m = rc.ic()
          m = m.collect { "${it}" }
          println "$m"
          m.collate(4).each{
              def deployments = [:]
              batch.each {
                deployments[it] = {
                   build job: 'jb', parameters: [string(name: 'pt', value: it), string(name: 'pl', value: params.gh), string(name: 'dc', value: params.nb)]
                }   
              
            }  
            parallel deployments
          }
        deployments["failFast"] = false
        }
    }
  } 
 }
```

Comment: similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198065/throttling-jenkins-parallel-in-pipeline

Comment: Could you also mention How many nodes and executors on each node you have? do you want that parallel run to be in a specific node or a randomly chosen node - If you have more than one node?

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel I have around 7 nodes and 5 executors on the node where this job is configured to run. I am failing to understand why this would run the jobs for batch sequentially. I was expecting to run four jobs in parallel then next 4 jobs in parallel

Comment: Do you want to pass FOUR ITEMS as parameters to ONE JOB, or do you want to run FOUR JOBS each with ONE ITEM as parameter? If the latter, do you want ALL OF THEM to finish (successfully?) before running another four jobs?

Comment: @MaratC I want to pass 4 items to the same job but need these batch of 4 jobs running in parallel. Once the first batch is finished, start the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done like this :

```
node {
    def items = (1..40).collect { "item-${it}" }
    items.collate(4).each { List batch -> 
        def n=[:]
        
        batch.each {
            n[it] = {
                stage(it) {
                    build job: 'x', parameters: [ string( name: "it", value : it) ]      
                }    
            }
        }
        
      parallel n
    }
}
```

**job: x Jenkinsfile content**

```
node {
    echo "Hello from Pipeline x"
    print params
}
```

This will invoke 4 jobs at a time and run parallelly. Make sure you have more than 4 executors configured on Jenkins.

[image]

Comment: I am getting below error ```hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: batch for class: WorkflowScript```

Comment: I hope you have copied all the code snippet from the above example and tried it or your Jenkins version is very old. could you share more details on this please?

Comment: I have updated my code in Description for your reference and my jenkins is Jenkins ver. 2.222.4

Comment: you have missed receiving parameter `m.collate(4).each{` here . it has to like `m.collate(4).each{List batch ->`

Comment: Thanks , it works but only thing is it do not return correct build status if one of the job fails

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
def items = (1..40).collect { "item-${it}" }
items.collate(4).each { List batch -> 
  // batch is now a list of 4 items, do something with it here
}
```

to use the groovy [Iterable.collate](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collate(int)) method to split the items into batches of four items and loop through the batches.

If you really want to do this "in parallell" as in using multiple threads, then that is a different question.

Comment: Will it run the code inside the block for all  4 items at once?

Comment: You get handed four items at once. What you do with the items at that point is up to you. Your question wasn't clear enough on the details to provide you with more detail in the answer.

Comment: I have updated the code in my description, I am trying to invoke another job for 4 items at once, but I do not see that happening, it is actually running in sequence for first one , waiting for it to finish and then doing next one